# Vue Firebase Chrome authentication

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication

I have an app that I created from a great tutorial (https://medium.com/@anas.mammeri/vue-2-firebase-how-to-build-a-vue-app-with-firebase-authentication-system-in-15-minutes-fdce6f289c3c)

It was working for me yesterday but today I'm getting an error when I try to authenticate with Firebase.  The error is '**auth/network-request-failed A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred.**'

Looking at other SO's with this problem([Firebase authentication failing with auth/network-request-failed A network error (such as timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43803855/firebase-authentication-failing-with-auth-network-request-failed-a-network-error)), I tried hard coding the signin:

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword("myid@mycompany.com", 
"password").catch(function(error) {   // Handle Errors here.
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
     console.log(errorCode + " " + errorMessage);   // ...   });
```

What I've found is that the code runs without a problem on **Firefox**, but logs the error above on chrome. I also notice that even though the firebase code is running in Chrome (as evidenced by stepping through it in debug), the Chrome tools report that the initialized firebase reference is undefined.
Has anyone encountered this and found a reasone/solution?

Comment: Appears to be a caching issue but not fixable by disabling caching in dev tools, but can be cleared through Clear browsing data.  Still interested if anyone else is experiencing this with Vue.js/Chrome